# Cyber/Bioware to enhance Knowledge Skills

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, knowledge-check, content-identification, cyberware

Last session, when I was bored and looking to burn some hard earned money for my character, I browsed through our books and found a nice little piece that when implanted would give +3 dice on all knowledge skill checks. At the time I considered it cheap and useful and something to install when the time comes.

Now that time has come and I cannot remember the name. Or book it came from. Or anything really. Just that it was relatively cheap and gave +3 dice for knowledge checks (not a general bonus to LOG or INT though). It may have been cyberware, it may have been bioware (more likely) or maybe even nano or gene stuff.

I browsed every book I could find and googled, but with nothing to search for, it's really just going through the lists one by one. And obviously I suck at that, because I found nothing.

So does anybody know what I'm talking about and can give me a hint where to find it? I have both English and German books for page references, but a name would be enough to be able to actually do a proper search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could have been the *Mnemonic Enhancer* (rating * 9,000 nuyen) from the core rulebook (page 460):

> **Mnemonic enhancer**: This highly concentrated
>   growth of grey matter gets attached to the brain’s memory
>   centers, improving both short- and long-term memory.
>   **Add the enhancer’s Rating as a dice pool bonus to
>   your Knowledge**, Language, and memory-related tests
>   as well as to your Mental limit.

Checking the *Chrome and Flesh* source book, the closest things are the **Knowledge Hardwire** (page 80), which increases a single skill defined by the 'ware, **Math SPU** (same page), which increases your Mathematics skill, and **Knowledge Infusion** (page 118), which grants a single rank on a knowledge skill you don't possess.

Comment: Core rulebook... doh... I guess I missed that, I only checked CF and a few others.

Comment: Ah, I was already searching through my 4ed books, as the mnemonic enhancer doesn't *specifically* say "+3 to knowledge skills" but "*rating* to knowledge skills".